Google Cloud Run: Container Fails to Start and Listen on Specified Port Despite Local Success
Problem
I'm deploying a FastAPI app with Uvicorn on Google Cloud Run. The app runs fine locally, but on Cloud Run, the deployment fails with the error:
Revision 'chat-api-00001-mcn' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable within the allocated timeout.

Details
1. Environment:

Container: Python 3.10 on Debian Bookworm.
Application: FastAPI app running via Uvicorn, using Google Cloud Storage and an OpenAI API key.
Credentials: Google Cloud Storage requires service account credentials via JSON key file, which I have set up as a Google Secret.
Dockerfile: I've configured the Dockerfile to expose port 8080 as expected by Cloud Run, and I use $PORT in the CMD command:

2. dockerfile
# Use a newer Debian version that includes SQLite > 3.35
FROM python:3.10-bookworm

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget build-essential libsqlite3-dev
RUN wget https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-autoconf-3410200.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf sqlite-autoconf-3410200.tar.gz && \
    cd sqlite-autoconf-3410200 && \
    ./configure && make && make install && \
    cd .. && rm -rf sqlite-autoconf-3410200*

# Set up app files and dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /chatbot/requirements.txt
COPY app /chatbot/app
WORKDIR /chatbot
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

# Expose port for Cloud Run
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["sh", "-c", "uvicorn app.chat_api:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT"]

3. Environment Variable Setup:

OPENAI_API_KEY and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS are set in the deployment command.
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS points to a secret mounted by Cloud Run.

4. Local Tests:

Goal: To ensure the Dockerized FastAPI app runs correctly before deployment.
Result: The container works as expected when run locally with docker run -p 8080:8080. API requests return expected responses without any errors.

docker run -p 8080:8080 \
  -e PORT=8080 \
  -e OPENAI_API_KEY="my_openai_api_key" \
  -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/app/credentials.json' \
  -v '/path/to/local/credentials.json:/app/credentials.json' \
  europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/chatbot/chatbot-api-repo/chatbot-api:0.3

5. Deployment Attempts:

Attempt #1: Set PORT=8080 and confirmed it matches the exposed port. Used --update-secrets to load Google credentials from a secret.
Attempt #2: Changed the path in the application to /secrets/chatbot-key, which is the correct path for Cloud Run secrets.
Attempt #3: Updated Dockerfile explicitly to use port 8080, but the error persists.

6. Logs:
The Cloud Run logs indicate a FileNotFoundError related to the Google credentials file, even though it exists and is specified in --update-secrets.
Question
Why does the container fail to start on Cloud Run with a port or credential error, even though it works perfectly locally? Could there be an issue with how Cloud Run handles port exposure or secrets mounting that I might be overlooking?
Any insights on solving this Cloud Run deployment issue would be appreciated!

You answer your own question in '6. Logs:', your deployment is incorrectly providing the credentials to the container at deployment. What is your (redacted) Cloud Run deployment command?

You shouldn't use a JSON key file on Cloud Run, you should use the linked service account. Credentials are available via the local metadata server, but GCP libraries know how to find them so it should just work even if you don't do anything.
